# Counting items in Jitterbit JSON transformation

Tags: conditional-statements, jitterbit

I am trying to create a Jitterbit condition which depending on the json passed into it will call one of two operations if true or false.

The previous transformation filters the JSON using a transformation condition so if a certain piece of data exists or not in the JSON it will return either one or no items in the JSON.

How do I create a condition after this which will branch depending on whether one or no items are passed to this? I was expecting something like :

json$item.Count 'GREATER THAN' 0

to work?

Thanks
Martin

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Solved using scripting in Jitterbit (Javascript rather than the Jitterbit scripting)